# Resize ListBox not resizing its items

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, resize

So i'm resizing a ListBox using a Storyboard. The relevant key

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.75" To="-276" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ItemList" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
```

But the items are getting squished.Is the a way to avoid this?

Comment: 1. What do you mean getting squished? Can you show a screenshot? 2. TranslateY is used to move the item, not resize it. I am not sure how you are resizing the listbox with Translate. 3. Do you mean squished or clipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are resizing the ListBox use

- Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)"

and/or

- Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Height)"

This should not affect the items in any way but will allow the ListBox to resize.

TranslateY will only move the control along the Y axis, not resize it.